# Constant Load pattern via JMeter

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am using JMeter to generate load for Azure Event Hub to do performance testing. I want to have constant load in Event Hub( at the time of message ingestion). I tried follwoing options.

1. Constant Throughput Timer
2. Number of active threads(users) -100 and ramp up time - 20 seconds.

I am not getting constant load in Event Hub. Getting too much spikes in Event hub. Please suggest a way to get constant load in Event hub via JMeter.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter is capable of creating a constant load pattern, just make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article, the essential points are:

1. [Run JMeter in non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. Ensure that JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, network and disk IO, etc. This can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
3. It might also be the case your application and/or middleware configuration is not appropriate for high constant load, check out i.e. [Concurrent, High Throughput Performance Testing with JMeter](https://howtojboss.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/concurrent-high-throughput-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) where the guy initially had load pattern like this:

   [image]

   and after tuning his application and JMeter he got to the following result:

   [image]

Comment: thanks but I am alreday using non-GUI mode and using OS Sampler.

Comment: OS Process Sampler is designed for [executing 3rd-party commands and programs from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/), if the spikes are caused by the external program - there is nothing you can do about it, consider moving the logic from that program to JMeter, there is a chance you can achieve the same using [JMeter Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) or [Groovy scripting](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-java).

Comment: but same 3rd party program was able to generate constant load using Visual Studio load test. currently VS Load Test is retired.

Comment: Then your JMeter configuration differs from the Visual Studio Load test

Comment: yes, In visual studio we have concept of agents and users but Jmeter supports users only

Comment: JMeter's equivalent for the "agent" is the "slave", check out [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) article for more information on JMeter client-server architecture for distributed clustered tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211157/discussion-between-amit-agrawal-and-dmitri-t).

Comment: Can we run OS Sampler in Distributed testing mode in JMeter ??